# Why Amazon Sandbox orders are always pending?

Tags: php, xml, api, amazon-mws

I'm using CBA (HTML Integration). After all steps are done, Amazon redirects to custom confirmation page with GET amznPmtsOrderIds. Then I'm trying to get Order details with MWS API (Action=GetOrder), it returns XML, but that XML doesn't contain important information such as: BuyerName, PostalCode, AddressLine1 and etc., because Order is still pending.

So how can I receive Order details + Order items after I have been redirected to confirmation page, knowing only Amazon Order Id?

Comment: After long searching for my question, found solution, On Checkout Pipeline Settings > Merchant URL, Amazon will send XML to it with all required data!

Comment: Just FYI, you can and should add answer your own question so that others can easily find the solution. Once you post your answer be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After long searching for my question, found solution, On Checkout Pipeline Settings > Merchant URL, Amazon will send XML to it with all required data! –  Oleg Andreyev Sep 27 '12 at 8:21

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are receiving the information.  Right now I am working on a google checkout interface, and although it is returning XML I am still using a _GET to get the informational.

Why not dump the entire results to a page and read though them to be sure you don't need to do something like..

buyer.billing-information.address  (If using a get the '.' are automatically replaced by '_')  if you can post most information I will try to help further.